# Show in the correct place caption when consecutive kable are applied

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

If I apply `kable` in the same or consecutive chunks with the option `echo = FALSE`, the first `caption` I specify appears above the first object to which I applied `kable` without `caption` above the other one. For example:

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(summary(cars))
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), caption = "Head of mtcars")
```
````

In this case, `Head of mtcars` appears above `kable(summary(cars))` in the output file.

Can be this solved by some way?

Thank you!

Comment: @yihui-xie Thank you. I saw the answer to the question you linked. But then, if I have both instructions in the same chunk, is there an alternative to `<!-- -->` without separate the chunk?

Comment: `knitr::asis_output('\n\n<!-- -->\n\n')`